# I was wet or I was wet with the rain

Tags: phrase-meaning

During one of our conversations, my friend said, “Because I was wet I couldn’t go to office”. I immediately corrected her to say, “Because I was wet “with the rain” I couldn’t go to office”.

In my understanding, I thought my friend has to mention the reason of her getting wet; otherwise it could be understood that she might have peed in her pants. Please correct me.

Comment: *Babies* are said to ***be wet*** when their nappy needs to be changed, but no-one in their right mind would assume that sense in reference to a normal adult.

Comment: One purpose of language is so that others correctly understand what one is communicating. Just saying "I was wet" unfortunately leaves a lot of opportunity for misunderstanding. So adding the additional detail (such as "from the rain") would always be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expressions your friend might use are

> I was **soaking** wet because of the rain.
>   I was **all** wet because of the rain.
>   I **got** all wet in the rain.

You are correct to think she needs to say the reason why, if she only says

> I was wet

it can have a very different meaning, and not just pee in the pants.

Comment: Sure, "I was wet" can have other meanings. But are any of them really likely as reasons that an adult couldn't go to the office?

Comment: Depends how wet I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

> Because I was wet I couldn’t go to the office.

(Note the insertion of "the".)  This isn't particularly idiomatic but I don't see any great problem with it.

I've never heard "I was wet" to mean "I've peed my pants" (I would say "I've wet myself"). Even if it does have that meaning in some places, it seems unlikely that somebody would want to say "Because I'd peed my pants, I couldn't go to the office." Likewise, it seems unlikely that somebody would want to say, "Because I was sexually aroused, I couldn't go to the office."

So, the only meaning that seems likely is "Because my clothes had some kind of liquid on them, I couldn't go to the office."  Other answers have suggested more idiomatic ways of saying this.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this expression. Your friend could say:

> Because I got wet in the rain I couldn't go to the office.

In my Google search, I found the following example in Merriam-Webster dictionary:

> The grass was wet with the morning dew.